# Why below exception safety code using auto_ptr is different?

Tags: c++, exception

Here's code which is not exception safe

```
//Header file declaration
void f(auto_ptr<T1>, auto_ptr<T2>);

//Implementation file:
f(auto_ptr<T1>(new T1), auto_ptr<T2>(new T2));
```

Exception safe solution to above is suggested as :

```
//Implementation file:
{
    auto_ptr<T1> t1(new T1);
    auto_ptr<T2> t2(new T2);
    f(t1, t2);
}
```

My question is why it's different when both uses auto_ptr to handle resource allocation?

This problem-solution is part of "More Exceptional C++" by Herb Sutter.

Comment: There's a good discussion of it in [this gotw](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/). The point is either of the calls to `new` can throw before the other `auto_ptr` object is fully constructed, leaking the resources allocated with the other call to `new`.

Comment: What part of Herb's explanation don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with first code snippet is that the order two sub-expressions building f() parameters will be executed is undefined by C++ Standard.
That is, if it happens like:

- Allocate & construct T1
- auto_ptr takes ownership of T1
- Allocate & construct T2
- auto_ptr takes ownership of T2

this would work perfectly fine.
But it is quite possible that the order will be like:

- Allocate & construct T1
- Allocate & construct T2
- auto_ptr takes ownership of T1
- auto_ptr takes ownership of T2

And in case if step 2 (alloc T2) throws, the already allocated memory for T1 will leak irretrievably.

For to prevent this, explicit ordering is done in the second code snippet you've provided.